# How should a crc32 be stored in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a crc32 in PHP and need to store it in a field in a MySQL database. After reading about how there is a concern about the results on a 32-bit vs 64-bit machine, I'm wondering how this number should be stored. This is how I'm treating the crc32 in PHP to get the same result on either bitsize machine:

```
<?php
$checksum = crc32("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.");
// On a 32-bit system it prints -2103228862 instead of
// 2191738434 which is correct and what prints on a 64-bit system. 
// See the php.net manual page on crc32 for more information about
// 32-bit vs 64-bit.
echo "checksum without printf formatting: " . $checksum . "\n";
printf("%u\n", $checksum);
$string = sprintf("%u", $checksum);
echo $string . "\n";
?>
```

Output (on a 64-bit machine is):

```
checksum without printf formatting: 2191738434
2191738434
2191738434
```

How should this number be stored on MySQL? Here are a few choices I've come up with so far:

```
`hash1` CHAR(10) NOT NULL ,
`hash2` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
`hash3` int unsigned NOT NULL,
```

It looks like I should go with:

```
`hash4` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
```

Comment: Simply use a 64 bits unsigned field (UNSIGNED BIGINT).

Answer (score 7):

You can store the values in MySQL as `INT UNSIGNED` which occupies 4 bytes (i.e. 32 bits).

To insert the values into the database, you must use `sprintf()` with `%u` format on 32 bit machines:

```
$hash = crc32("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.");

$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (:hash)');
$stmt->execute(array(
    ':hash' => sprintf('%u', $hash),
));
```

**Update**

You could also make sure that you're always working with int32 types (signed long) on both 32 and 64-bit platforms. Currently, you can only accomplish this by using [`pack()`](http://php.net/pack) and [`unpack()`](http://php.net/unpack):

```
echo current(unpack('l', pack('l', $hash)));
// returns -2103228862 on both 32-bit and 64-bit platforms
```

The idea for this was contributed by [mindplay.dk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/283851/mindplay-dk)

Comment: Be warned that loading a hashed value back from a table will cause it to cast back to a signed integer - after a big fiasco (and a lot of mopping up afterwards) I [strongly recommend](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.crc32.php#113079) sticking to signed integers, which behave the same on 32 and 64 bit platforms. Try `unpack('l', pack('l', crc32(...)))` which is the simplest way I could find to guarantee portable results.

Comment: @mindplay.dk That depends on how you retrieve it as most database layers will return it as a string value; having said that, the need to have a consistent int32 is worth an update on my answer :)

Comment: Some modern DB layers will type-cast `INTEGER` columns to actual integers, so that you can write clean code using strict `===` comparison. Thanks for crediting me for the idea in your update :-)